# Google APIのOAuth2認証時にinvalid_scopeが発生するようになった

Tags: php, api, oauth, google-api

google-api-php-clientを使用してphpでGmailAPIにアクセスをしておりますが、
以前よりクライアントIDでの認証を行っておりました。

最近になって、Developer Consoleから新たにWebアプリケーションのクライアントIDを追加し、追加したクライアントIDのJSONファイルを使って認証を行おうすると、以下のようなエラーメッセージが出るようになり、認証が通らなくなりました。

承認済みのJavaScript生成元は、既に利用していたドメインも新規で取得したドメインも両方認証が通らない状態です。

```
400. エラーが発生しました。

エラー: invalid_scope

このアプリは次のスコープへのアクセスの確認が完了していません: 
{invalid = [https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose]}。
サポートについてデベロッパーにお問い合わせください。
デベロッパーの方は、このプロジェクトで上記のスコープが必要な場合は、プロジェクトへのアクセス権限があるアカウントにログインして、もう一度お試しください。
必要でない場合は、サポートについてデベロッパーにお問い合わせください。

Request Details
client_id=xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

Google で確認できたことは以上です。
```

これまでと何が違うものかと調べているのですが、原因がわからず質問させて頂きました。
新たに追加したクライアントIDの認証を通す方法が変わったのでしょうか...？

下記、該当のコードです。

```
<?php

$isDebug = false;

require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

session_start();

if ($isDebug) {
    var_dump($_SESSION)."<br/>";
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(array(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM, Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_COMPOSE, Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY, Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY));

try {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();

        $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
                $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
            } else {
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    if (isset($authUrl)) {
        header('Location: '.$authUrl);
        exit;
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    unset($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
    unset($_SESSION['google_client']);
    exit;
}

$_SESSION['google_client'] = $client;
echo 'OAuth success.'."\n";

function debug($isDebug, $msg) {
    if ($isDebug) {
        echo $msg;
    }
}

?>
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 5月にポリシーの変更があったようですがその影響でしょうか https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes?hl=ja  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928334 手元では再現しないので確証はないのですが

Comment: @suzukis ありがとうございます。まさにそれが原因でした。解決策はこちらの記事の通りです。http://qiita.com/iuvo-duo/items/e5e9563d11aac164d0a6

Comment: よろしければコメントではなく自分で回答書いてください

Comment: 失礼しました。回答の方に転記しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

具体的な解決策を書いておきます。①OAuth Developer Verification Formで承認を受ける support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification ②Allow Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Appsのフォーラムに参加する groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-a‌​pps（残念ながら承認はまだ通ってないの‌​で、未承認の方で対応としました）

Answer (score 0):

ここで言っていることかもしれません。

GAS で「一部のスコープへのアクセス権限がありません」と怒られたときの対処法
http://qiita.com/zk_phi/items/7220b67afa84c58cc160

Comment: 他サイトへのリンクにのみ解決法が残っているような回答は避け、回答の中にも具体的な内容が書かれているようにしてください。リンクは切れることがあるためです。

Comment: これはGoogle Apps Scriptの話でエラーメッセージも一致しませんので「似ているが違う話」ではないでしょうか。「違う話に見えるが同じこと」なのであれば、それを明示するとともにソースも示してもらうとよい回答になります。

Comment: 皆様コメントありがとうございます。suzukisさんの仰る通り、今回の事象とはまた異なるものでした。